# My Italian meringue macarons won’t stop coming out hollow

Tags: baking, sugar, meringue, macarons

I’ve been making Macarons for a while but I have recently started to try the Italian method for making them and have basically failed 95% of the time. I’ve probably made around 25 batches all that have come out extremely hollow. I’ve tried like 15 to 20 different oven temperatures and times, all which have failed. I’ve invested in an oven thermometer and my oven is working as it supposed to; it’s a brand new oven, only about a year and a half old. I’m pretty positive that the entire macaron assembling stages are on point. I know the macaronage is essential and can be easily messed up but I am confident that I’m doing it correctly and that my problem is the oven temperature and time because my macarons have come out fine a couple times. I have a whirlpool electric oven. i’ve tried temperatures like 300F+ for 12-14 min and that cracked my shells. I tried 295F for 20 minutes and that made them dry and overcooked. I tried 275 convection for 10 minutes, then flipped the pan and baked another 10 and they were also hollow. I believe I’ve tried 285 as well and everything in between. I’m really not sure on where I should position my racks and what other temperatures I should try. I’m getting desperate and I just need to figure out what temperature works so that I can stop wasting so many ingredients!

Please help!

Comment: You need to edit and add detail on the method you are using to make them. The problem could be the method, not the temperature.

Comment: Tried the resting and rapping the tray on the bench to remove bubbles?

Comment: @bob1 yes most definitely. I Never skip that. I know it’s not the method that I’m using to make them because I’ve had them checked by a professional baker

Comment: Banging the tray is a french meringue macaron technique, I don't think it applies to Italian .